# Comparing two integer values pointed to

Tags: c++, pointers

Inspired by the current top answer to this popular [question concerning getting the larger of two values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985069/451600).

Consider a function that accepts two integer pointers, and returns a pointer. Both pointers might be `nullptr`.

```
const int*  max(const int* a, const int* b);
```

If a or b is a `nullptr` return the non-null pointer. If both are `nullptr`, return `nullptr`.

If both are valid pointers return `max(*a, *b);`.

The currently most upvoted answer for the C# question is

```
int? c = a > b ? a ?? b : b ?? a;
```

int? represents a nullable value, not unlike a pointer.

**How can this be expressed in an elegant and idiomatic fashion in c++?**

My immediate attempt was along the lines of

```
const int* maxp(const int* a, const int* b){
   if (!a) return b;
   if (!b) return a;
   return &std::max(*a, *b); 
}
```

Comment: No problem with temporaries here, `std::max` returns a reference to the bigger element. I consider your code *vastly* superior to any unreadable `?:` operator hack.

Comment: `std::optional<int>` is (will be) a better match for `Nullable<int>`, and it supports the same things. `auto c = b < a ? a.value_or(b) : b.value_or(a);` should do it unless I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

The temptation of the ternary operator is big

```
const int* maxp(const int *a, const int *b) {
    return a? (b? &std::max(*a, *b) : a) : b;
}
```

but it's because it's funny, not because it's better.

The code in the question is more readable.

Comment: I actually find this quite readable (without the parenthesis it might be a bit confusing.)

Answer (score -2):

There is problem with your code, which is that it is returning a pointer to the output of std::max.  Taking the address of the output of a function is usually buggy, and always in poor taste.  It is only correct if the function returns a reference to a variable that will persist as long as the pointer is held.

I would replace the last line of your function with a simple if statement:

```
if (*a > *b) return a;
else return b;
```

This way you will always return one of the pointers that were the input to your function.

P.S. I have glanced at the standard regarding `std::max`, and had trouble understanding it.  But ultimately, even if your code does work (because `std::max` returns a reference), it is better not to take the address of said reference.

P.P.S. Avoiding the ternary operator is by far best in terms of clarity here.  The rest of your function is fine.